# Twilio call next person from queue using PHP Laravel

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have this code in `laravel`

```
$client->calls->create(
     array(
        'from'=> '+6326263667',
        'to'=> ???,
        'url'=> 'twilio bin url'
     )
);
```

I don't know what to put in the "to" array. I'm copying the node version of this like:

```
client.calls.create({
   from: from,
   to: process.argv[2],
   url: url
})`
```

it there any other way if not like this?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

The [`to` field](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#post-parameters) is expecting the telephone number (in [E.164 format](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164)) you wish to call.

In your Node example there, `process.argv[2]` is referring to the first argument passed to a command line operation.

If you want to learn more, I recommend you check out the [Programmable Voice Quickstart for PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/php).

Comment: what about if I want to answer the person in the queue? what number will I put in the "to" field assuming that I don't know the number of the person in the queue?